# One to one relationship vs one to many

Tags: database, mongodb

I have two collections: movies collection and comments collection, I want users to be able to post comments about a movie.
I can either have any movie contain an array which contains the id's of each comment or I can have any comment contain the id of the movie to whom it belongs. What are the downsides and advantages of each method?

This is more of a theoretical question. so lets assume that comments are too large and cannot be embedded into the movies collection.

Answer (score 0):

This question is difficult to answer. In NoSQL DB (like your "mongodb" used tag indicates your are using it), the choice of using two collections, OR a collection with embedded comment's _id in an array, OR one single collection with embedded comments information **really depends on your use cases.**

1. With SQL database you can create a movie table and a comment table, with movie's id in comment element.
2. With nosql, you have to choose regarding your use cases : is your page displaying a movies list first with associated comments ? do you have a page which is listing last comments whatever movie ? You have also to integrate technical requirements/restrictions in your reflexion. Example, with mongodb you have a main restriction :
   BSON Document Size - The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

> The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot
> use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount
> of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB
> provides the GridFS API. See mongofiles and the documentation for your
> driver for more information about GridFS.

Check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/ for more precisions.

My first reflexion regarding your needs and **my global representation of what you want to do with your app** is regarding the following use case :

- A page is listing all movies (you can eventualy filter on different movie's flags). So, *your entry point is a movie*, not a comment. *A comment is related to only one movie*, a comment is not for more than one movie.
- For each movie, an user can display associated comments and add a new comment.
  For this use case, a performant db organisation is : One single collection for movies. A movie embed a list of comments, directly embedded in an array of JSON objects, like :

> {
> "_id":"m001",
> "title":"Movie1",
> "synopsis":"A young girl want to learn chess and becomes the best player in the world, his name: Beth harmone",
> "comments":[
> {
> "_id":"c001",
> "title":"Good movie",
> "commentText":"This is a very good movie"
> },
> {
> "_id":"c002",
> "title":"Annoying movie",
> "commentText":"This is a very  annying movie"
> }
> ]
> }

You don't need to create another collection to store comments, you will loose reactivity, because of joining from movie another collection comment. BUT, this is a good choice only if you think each of your whole movies element will not be bigger than 16MB (you can also integrate GridFS API as indicated by MongoDB doc, but not the subject here...).

Alternatively, IF you think millions and millions of comments, with lot of information, can be added to a single movie, you will be blocked by technical limitation. In this case, it is better to split into two collections, with it, the technical limitation will not hurt you : each comment will be an element on "comment" collection and will certainly not reach 16MB.

Ffinally, noSQL DB performances can be really really better than SQL DB but you have to **design your DB model regarding your use case**.
I hope to be clear.

Useful links :

- https://www.mongodb.com/basics/embedded-mongodb
- https://fosterelli.co/collections-and-embedded-documents-in-mongodb (particularly "Example: comments on a blog" which seems to be your use case)